# Can no longer access administration pages - Warning/Error

Tags: 7

Today, I logged in as administrator to my Drupal 7 site. I was using overlay, viewing "People", and everything was working fine. Then I clicked on "Reports".

All of a sudden, I had a white screen, and can no longer access any of the administration pages of my site. When clicking back to the home screen, I get multiple instances of this error:

Warning: require_once(C:\inetp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in module_load_include() (line 330 of C:\inetpub\wwwroot\includes\module.inc).

I was using the administration pages just fine a couple days ago. I'm not sure what could of happened. The only thing recent was I updated Views - but this was quite a little while back - and again, had no problems after that up until now.

Can someone help?
Thanks!

Comment: check and follow this link https://www.drupal.org/node/482956 "Fixing white screens step by step"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all of a sudden now - the problem is gone. I did nothing to fix it. I went to the recent log messages, and I saw that cron was run just before this last successful attempt.

So perhaps running cron fixed the issue.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

go to your `settings.php` and add this code below

```
error_reporting(-1);  // Have PHP complain about absolutely everything 
$conf['error_level'] = 2;  // Show all messages on your screen, 2 = ERROR_REPORTING_DISPLAY_ALL.
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);  // These lines just give you content on WSOD pages.
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

follow these steps Blank pages or "[white screen of death](https://www.drupal.org/node/158043)" (WSOD)